# getting error on line recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

**logcat** 2020-11-05 22:49:22.581 1663-1663/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1025 com.android.server.location.OppoSuplController.sendSuplConfigUpdateBroadcast:293 com.android.server.location.OppoSuplController.updateSuplConfig:274 com.android.server.location.OppoSuplController.access$1300:47 com.android.server.location.OppoSuplController$2.handleMessage:619  2020-11-05 22:49:22.582 1663-1663/? D/OppoSuplController: mSuplHostName : supl.google.com, mSuplHostPort : 7275, mSuplMode : 3, mMsaEnabled : true, mMsbEnabled : true, mSpecHostEnabled : true, mHostSwitchEnabled : true, mTelephonyImsi : 40494 2020-11-05 22:49:22.620 2935-2935/? D/CdmaVolteServiceChecker: onReceive, action
= android.intent.action.SERVICE_STATE 2020-11-05 22:49:22.620 2935-2935/? D/CdmaVolteServiceChecker: updateState, checking = false 2020-11-05 22:49:22.620 2935-2935/? D/CdmaVolteServiceChecker: shouldShowVolteAlert cdma mixed volte support, return false. 2020-11-05 22:49:22.844 1663-3532/? E/Process: get_ion_cache_memory: Unable to open /d/ion/heaps/system 2020-11-05 22:49:22.980 1663-4211/? E/Process: get_ion_cache_memory: Unable to open /d/ion/heaps/system 2020-11-05 22:49:25.681 22324-22457/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here. 2020-11-05 22:49:27.649 1173-1382/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0 2020-11-05 22:49:28.068 1663-1663/? D/BatteryService: send broadcast : oppo.intent.action.BATTERY_DATA_UPDATE 2020-11-05 22:49:28.069 1663-1663/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1025 com.android.server.BatteryService$8.run:803 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:873 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:99 android.os.Looper.loop:226  2020-11-05 22:49:29.396 10556-10598/? W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value. 2020-11-05 22:49:29.520 1663-1663/? D/Intent: disableDeathOnFileUriExposure com.android.chrome 2020-11-05 22:49:29.568 19152-19332/? I/BtGatt.ScanManager: msg.what = 6 2020-11-05 22:49:29.591 818-818/? I//vendor/bin/hw/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0-service: size of service connections for service: com.android.chrome/org.chromium.components.background_task_scheduler.BackgroundTaskJobServiceafter removal is 0 2020-11-05 22:49:29.591 818-818/? I//vendor/bin/hw/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0-service: size of client connections for client: systemafter removal is 16 2020-11-05 22:49:29.593 22324-23131/? D/Intent: disableDeathOnFileUriExposure com.android.chrome 2020-11-05 22:49:29.611 22324-22324/? E/cr_BkgrdTaskJS: Tried finishing non-current BackgroundTask. 2020-11-05 22:49:29.683 14000-24041/? E/MCS2.0_CIPHER_ALGO: checkSign 1   2020-11-05 22:49:29.691 14000-24041/? D/MCS2.0_CIPHER_ALGO: riv native_AES_encrypt flag 0 2020-11-05 22:49:34.182 1663-2761/? W/Watchdog: !@WatchDog_3773 2020-11-05 22:49:29.705 14000-24041/? D/MCS2.0_CIPHER_ALGO: riv native_AES_encrypt flag 0 2020-11-05 22:49:34.577 1663-1663/? D/Intent: disableDeathOnFileUriExposure com.facebook.katana 2020-11-05 22:49:34.622 19152-19332/? I/BtGatt.ScanManager: msg.what = 6 2020-11-05 22:49:35.253 818-818/? I//vendor/bin/hw/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0-service: size of service connections for service: com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.analytics2.logger.LollipopUploadServiceafter removal is 0 2020-11-05 22:49:35.253 818-818/? I//vendor/bin/hw/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0-service: size of client connections for client: systemafter removal is 16 2020-11-05 22:49:38.656 1663-1673/? I/system_server: Background concurrent copying GC freed 90991(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 40(976KB) LOS objects, 17% free, 36MB/44MB, paused 563us total 168.097ms 2020-11-05 22:49:38.830 1663-1663/? D/BatteryService: send broadcast : oppo.intent.action.BATTERY_DATA_UPDATE 2020-11-05 22:49:38.831 1663-1663/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1025 com.android.server.BatteryService$8.run:803 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:873 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:99 android.os.Looper.loop:226  2020-11-05 22:49:39.072 1663-4881/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/blackCheckStatus (No such file or directory) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.073 1663-4881/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.073 1663-4881/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.073 1663-4881/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:165) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.073 1663-4881/? W/System.err:     at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:514) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.073 1663-4881/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.BootReceiver$2.run(BootReceiver.java:232) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.074 1663-4882/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/brightCheckStatus (No such file or directory) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.075 1663-4882/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.075 1663-4882/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.075 1663-4882/? W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:165) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.075 1663-4882/? W/System.err:     at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:514) 2020-11-05 22:49:39.075 1663-4882/? W/System.err:     at com.android.server.BootReceiver$3.run(BootReceiver.java:259) 2020-11-05 22:49:40.739 818-818/? I//vendor/bin/hw/vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0-service: size of client connections for client: com.android.chromeafter removal is 3 2020-11-05 22:49:41.368 5961-5965/? E/rutils: releaseProcess gCount = 1 2020-11-05 22:49:41.475 10556-10598/? W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value. 2020-11-05 22:49:49.067 1663-1663/? D/BatteryService: send broadcast : oppo.intent.action.BATTERY_DATA_UPDATE 2020-11-05 22:49:49.068 1663-1663/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1025 com.android.server.BatteryService$8.run:803 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:873 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:99 android.os.Looper.loop:226  2020-11-05 22:49:53.552 10556-10598/? W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value. 2020-11-05 22:49:55.710 22324-22457/? E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here. 2020-11-05 22:50:00.080 1663-1663/? D/BatteryService: send broadcast : oppo.intent.action.BATTERY_DATA_UPDATE 2020-11-05 22:50:00.081 1663-1663/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1025 com.android.server.BatteryService$8.run:803 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:873 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:99 android.os.Looper.loop:226
**builderror**

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project G:\SOFTWARES\Recyclerview

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:processDebugResources

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac G:\SOFTWARES\Recyclerview\app\src\main\java\com\example\recyclerview\MainActivity.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
> recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
> ^   symbol:   variable recyclerView   location: class id Note: G:\SOFTWARES\Recyclerview\app\src\main\java\com\example\recyclerview\ProductAdapter.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details. 1 error

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 14s 11 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 8 up-to-date

**Mainactivity.java** package com.example.recyclerview;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager; 
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //List<Product> ProductList;
     RecyclerView recyclerView;
     List<Object> productList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();


        //adding some items to our list
        productList.add(
                new Product(
                        1,
                        "Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra)",
                        "13.3 inch, Silver, 1.35 kg",
                        4.3,
                        60000,
                        R.drawable.macbook));

        productList.add(
                new Product(
                        1,
                        "Dell Inspiron 7000 Core i5 7th Gen - (8 GB/1 TB HDD/Windows 10 Home)",
                        "14 inch, Gray, 1.659 kg",
                        4.3,
                        60000,
                        R.drawable.dellinspiron));

        productList.add(
                new Product(
                        1,
                        "Microsoft Surface Pro 4 Core m3 6th Gen - (4 GB/128 GB SSD/Windows 10)",
                        "13.3 inch, Silver, 1.35 kg",
                        4.3,
                        60000,
                        R.drawable.surface));

        //creating recyclerview adapter
        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    } }
```

**layout.product.xml**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:padding="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:text="Apple MacBook Air Core i5 5th Gen - (8 GB/128 GB SSD/Mac OS Sierra)"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewShortDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:text="13.3 Inch, 256 GB"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewShortDesc"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="4.7"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small.Inverse"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/textViewRating"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
                android:text="INR 56990"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="354dp"
    android:layout_height="626dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayou

**I am making a recycler reference with the below website https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-cardview-tutorial/**

Comment: Does `activity_main` have recycler View in it ?

Comment: yes. i just opened a new project and imported androidx depencies  and just copied these code finally one erroir i cant execute in mainactivity.java line 22 showing redcolour error . i am a beginner . i dont know what to do now , can u find that mistake ?  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

Comment: looks like a cache error to me.
Try clearing cache 
Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart
or 
Go to Build > Rebuild Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the id in recyclerview.

**android:id="@+id/recyclerView"**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
          android:layout_width="354dp"
          android:layout_height="626dp"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```